# App version not getting updated

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-version

I've an application in the market. A month ago, I updated the application with newer version. I've changed the appVersionCode as well as appVersionName in the manifest file. In my database, I'll fetch the current version which user has got installed. In this database, for few of my users, I can observe that app'version still shows 2.2 when they have actually updated it to 2.3. For the rest, the app's version have got updated successfully. I tested my logic and flow as well. I could not recreate this problem. I'll be grateful to any one's help.

The database updation which I was talking about has the following code:

UserVersion is my local Database. It consists of Device's UID and Version of my app.

When a user installs next version, I get the Version of the application by using the following code:

```
PackageManager manager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = manager.getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = info.versionName;
```

If this version is different from my local database's version, I'll update it.

Mainfest file is shown below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sa.appoptix.com"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.2" >
```

Below this, uses permission and application tags are used.

Comment: It is impossible to give an advice if we don't know what you do exactly. How do you transfer the version to your server, how do you know the devices in question actually performed the update, ...

Comment: Please list all changes in the manifest for version 2.2 and version 2.3.

Comment: Please clarify this --- In my database, I'll fetch the current version which user has got installed.

Comment: I've edited my question with required code. Please help guys.

Comment: @NarendraDroidWorm: I've database, where, my app version will be stored along with user's email id. When a user updates my app's version, I'll update this database's value into the new one. Now my problem is that, for about 400 users, databse value has got updated. But for the rest, it has not got updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can update APP version from AndroidManifest.xml file , this is a configuration file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

version code increment by 1 when update new version.
version name  you can put it as this format 1.0 / 1.0.0 , 1.x.x